# How to remove background fading when modal box is opened

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How to remove modal background fade when modal is opened,I have a screen in which when a modal is opened it should get the scroll on background but which is hidden in my case.Can any one please suggest help.Thanks.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOcdN.png)

```
 <div class="modal fade registermodal" id="login-register-model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-body paddingbody">
            <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-body paddingmodal2">
                         <form id="login-form" name="loginForm" ng-if="showLoginForm" class="nobottommargin" novalidate="">
                         <div class="text-center social-login-sec">
                         <a class="col-xs-12 btn btn-primary social-login-btn"  id="facebook_login" rel='nofollow' href="/auth/facebook" target="_self" data-ng-click="onClickSocialBtn();">Facebook</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.modal-backdrop {
    z-index: 0;
 }
```

Comment: *it should get the scroll on background* I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Hi BSMP,i attached the screen shot,I am getting the scroll but unable to access it since it is faded.

Comment: So you want the page scrollable instead of the modal while the modal is open? Can I ask why? (Also, code demonstrating your issue would be a lot more helpful than a screenshot.)

Comment: Yes,I want my modal to be scrollable.

Comment: The normal default behavior of Bootstrap is for this to work. (If I use the demo modal code in the documentation and make it tall, I'm able to scroll it.) If you need someone to debug your code then you need to include enough of your code in the question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added code....

Comment: Sorry, but this code doesn't reproduce your issue. If I use this code, the scrolling works.

Answer (score 0):

It caused default by `bootstrap-modal`, when the modal open, your `body` get `addClass` named `modal-open`. That class make you cannot scroll it `{overflow: hidden}`

so to fix this you just need to remove the class, try this code

```
$('#login-register-model').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("body").removeClass("modal-open")
})
```

Hope it can help you :D

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/0fscmf3L/2625/

```css
.modal-body .form-horizontal .col-sm-2,
.modal-body .form-horizontal .col-sm-10 {
    width: 100%
}

.modal-body .form-horizontal .control-label {
    text-align: left;
}
.modal-body .form-horizontal .col-sm-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm">
    Launch Normal Form
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModalNorm" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" 
                   data-dismiss="modal">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Modal title
                </h4>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control"
                      id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control"
                          id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"/> Check me out
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control"
                      id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control"
                          id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"/> Check me out
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control"
                      id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control"
                          id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"/> Check me out
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                
                
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save changes
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.